# How to access symbol by name in mxnet?

Tags: python, mxnet

In mxnet 1.4 using the Python API, suppose I do

```
import mxnet as mx

var = mx.sym.var('a')
print(var)  # <Symbol a>

var = mx.sym.var('b')
print(var)  # <Symbol b>
```

How can I access Symbol `a` by name?

I would like  to do something like `var_a = mx.sym.get_by_name('a')`.

I have checked this [tutorial](https://mxnet.incubator.apache.org/versions/master/tutorials/basic/symbol.htm), the [docs](https://mxnet.incubator.apache.org/api/python/symbol/symbol.html), as well as the [source code](https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet/blob/master/python/mxnet/symbol/symbol.py) but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `get_internals()` or `get_children()` methods and then access individual symbols using their index -

```py
a = mx.sym.var('a')
b = mx.sym.var('b')
tmp = a * b

graph = tmp.get_internals()
print(graph)
print(graph[0])
print(tmp.get_children())
```

Output:

```
<Symbol group [a, b, _mul22]>
<Symbol a>
<Symbol group [a, b]>
```

Answer (score 0):

A messy way is to get a list of symbol names first, then query the list to get the index of the name, then use this index to query the symbol group.

```
symbol_output = last_layer.get_internals()
symbol_output_list = symbol_output.list_outputs()
# say the name is 'conv0_output'
conv0_index = symbol_output_list.index('conv0_output')
print(conv0_index)
# 8
print(symbol_output[conv0_index])
# <Symbol conv0>
```